# Managing SSH Connections

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, ssh

On a Linux server, how would I find a list of all current SSH connections, or disconnect a specific SSH connection?

Comment: Are you interested in incoming or outgoing SSH connections? or both?

Comment: This question is more relevant to [superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: I'm only interested with incoming connections.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're planning to do this interactively, the simplest would be to simply invoke `who` and see if there are any users from a remote host.

```
[you@host]$ who
user1      :0           Feb  8 09:45
user1      pts/1        Feb 14 17:56 (:0.0)
malcolm    pts/3        Feb 15 17:50 (cockpit.serenity.com)
reynold    pts/2        Feb 15 17:48 (host123.firefly.co.uk)
```

This is of course not foolproof, but is extremely simple to type up on demand and easily process with the human eye.

As @gravyface pointed out, if you include a `-u` option `who` will also print out the associated PID which you can then pass to `kill` to terminate a connection.

Comment: `-u` will give you the PID.

Comment: this does not show the IPs if there are multiple connections on one user

Comment: For some reason, this didn't work. From a remote machine, I logged into my machine using ssh, and in my machine, I executed a `who -u`. Killing the pid didn't terminate the connection on my remote machine. However, following that I did a `lsof -i | grep ":ssh"`  suggested in the answer by @kce, I got a different pid; killing that process terminated the connection. Maybe there are multiple processes that are started because of an ssh connection and killing the one displayed by who doesn't terminate the connection; that's my explanation.

Answer (score 8):

How about using lsof?

```
# lsof -i |grep ":ssh"

sshd    1943      root    3u  IPv6   5698       TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd    1943      root    4u  IPv4   5700       TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd    3217      root    3r  IPv4   9687       TCP www.example.com:ssh->192.168.61.11:7341 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    3220      user1   3u  IPv4   9687       TCP www.example.com:ssh->192.168.61.11:7341 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    3327      root    3r  IPv4  10595       TCP www.example.com:ssh->192.168.61.11:7385 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    3330      user2   3u  IPv4  10595       TCP www.example.com:ssh->192.168.61.11:7385 (ESTABLISHED)
```

You should then be able to kill the offending connection (e.g., to disconnect user2):

```
# kill -9 3330
```

Comment: Use `lsof -i tcp:22` and you won't need the grep.

Comment: Only if you run the `ssh` and don't specify the `-p` option..

Answer (score 1):

To view the ssh connections you can do a `netstat -atn | grep ':22'`. It shows all connections on port 22.

To drop the connection, you can try finding the PID of the sshd (SSH Daemon) with `ps-ax`.

Edit: I think you can find the PID of their `bash` session (or equivalent shell). Killing that should drop them alright.

Another resource: [this thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/killing-an-ssh-session-339440/) has some tips on the subject.

Comment: I have no active connections on my current machine, but netstat still lists a tcp and tcp6 connection. What would I do with the PID of sshd? Are you implying I should kill the entire SSH server just to drop a single connection?

Comment: @Cerin Those two connections show that it's listening on those ports (only)

Comment: You didn't specify, but I shoul have though of it. Sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$ ps aux | grep sshd`

To disconnect them you could `kill PID` (where `PID` is the process Id in the second column), if you have root privileges, or are the user in question.

Comment: This only shows sshd is running and the user the connection was established with (not number of connections, what IP it's from)